# How to show auto-focus and flash while using zxing bar code scanner?

Tags: ios, flash, focus, barcode, zxing

I'm working on a iOS application in which for scanning barcode I am using ZXing libray. I'm successfully able to scan the bar codes and able to display it on text box.

I tried to show atuo-focus (blinked centered rectangular selection area from camera) and try to use camera flash light while scanning, but both are not working.

Can any one answer me on following :

1. How to show auto-focus, a camera centered selection indicators while using zxing scan?
2. How to activate camera flash while scanning?

I would be very much thankful to you for providing me any sample code for both of them.